# Use of Amadeus Trip parser API

Tags: amadeus

UPDATE : Fix one problem with the content-type of the request which has to be `application/vnd.amadeus+json` ‍♂️ After the fix, lot of mails are not able to be parse without additional details. Amadeus support kind of confirmed me that my test mails are from providers that are not supported :/

I try to use Self-Service Trip Parser API https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/trip/api-doc/trip-parser

I did some testing using confirmation emails from well-known brand like Booking or Oui SNCF but with no success and generally got 500 generic errors.

What I do is :

- go to gmail, download the message as `.eml` format
- encode it to base 64 `base64 -i mail.eml | tr -d '\n' | pbcopy`
- create the payload to send to Amadeus using own Amadeus Swagger but got 500 errors in most case

```
{
  "data": {
    "type": "trip-parser-job",
    "content": "<paste mail content>"
  }
}
```

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "code": "38189",
            "title": "Internal error",
            "detail": "An internal error occurred, please contact your administrator",
            "status": "500"
        }
    ]
}
```

- In best case, the job is created, but the status is failure after a few minutes

Only using mail PDF attachment seems to work sometimes.

My questions are simple :

- do any of you make it works reliably ?
- is there any additional information on support input format or providers ?
- is there any worthwhile alternative ?

Comment: Does the html content of the `.eml` give better results? What do you want to do with the output by the way?

Comment: Got a problem with some mail, fix it and got lot of parsing failed error. Eventually got a feedback from Amadeus support : only a handful of providers are supported :/

Comment: That's too bad. If they charge money per call, I'd have assumed a great many providers were supported. You could parse the mails yourselves though. It shouldn't be too bad.